# What are the max number of elements that we can add to a list in java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
public static void FindMax()
{
    List<Integer> l=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    for(int i=0;i<Integer.MAX_VALUE;i++)
    {
        l.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println(l.size());
}
```

Its giving me the following exception :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Add more heap ;-)

Comment: Here's how you can increase [Java memory](https://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Java-Memory-in-Windows-7)!

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research. There are many questions like this.

Comment: The max amount of elements is as many as you have heap for. Add more heap, get more elements

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your heap space. But the maximum size since you're indexing it with int is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Alot of comments are there saying exactly same thing